# SSH to a remote server using PuTTY through Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, putty

On Windows I use PuTTY to log in to a remote server via SSH. I want to use a batch script to SSH to the remote server using PuTTY. The server is running a Linux-based OS.

I used the below command to do this:

```
start C:\Windows\System32\putty.exe -ssh server_name -l pankmish -pw wxyz
```

However I got the following error:

> unable to connect to remote host

If I use this command instead:

```
start C:\Windows\System32\putty.exe -ssh server_name -l user_name
```

Everything works well and I get a PuTTY window with username "user_name" in it. If I provide the correct password I am able to connect to the server. However via a batch script I am not able to provide the password when prompted.

How can I solve this?

Comment: did you use Plink to connect putty and remote server.

Comment: On Windows, you can create a Powershell script (using the ssh.net library) to connect to a remote server by SSH and automate a task.  See http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library

Comment: I tried using Plink also to connect putty and remote server, but error was same.

Comment: I think error is coming because password prompt is coming in next line of user name prompt. so please suggest me any example batch script to give password when it is prompted.

Comment: I tried same command->> start C:\Windows\System32\putty.exe -ssh server_name -l user -pw %1; and provided password from command line and it worked fine.

Comment: Might I suggest, that you should be using `SSH key-based authentication` vs Passwords, it will be more secure and easier to configure. (Though the most secure is Key-Based auth w/ password!)

Comment: See my related question here >> https://superuser.com/questions/1278434/create-a-batch-file-or-shortcut-to-putty-ssh-that-opens-a-session-and-runs-a-c/1279087#1279087

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried passing the password using command line and it worked fine for me.

```
start C:\Users\pankmish\Downloads\putty.exe -ssh server_name -l user -pw %1
```

and executed command from my windows cmd as below

> test_file.bat password

Comment: I'd suggest to surround `password` with double quotes every time, so in case if it contains spaces or other special characters there would be no problems in executing it properly

Comment: What if I want to run a command after logging in?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that putty is installed and putty.exe is present in C:\Windows\System32

Open up notepad: Type in the following

```
start putty <username@ip/hostname> -pw <password>
```

Replace the above with your username, ip and password and save the file as .bat file. I think that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the same trick of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767331/batch-file-for-changing-cmd-directory-and-pre-filling-a-command/22772040#22772040):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

rem Start the putty window with the user name only
start C:\Windows\System32\putty.exe -ssh server_name -l user_name

rem Send the password to putty window
%SendKeys% "wxyz{ENTER}"

goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Please, post the result.

Comment: Still same issue, not able to connect to the server. After running the above script; in password prompt password value is not being added.

Answer (score 1):

The below command is working for me as-is from inside of a bat file.

"D:\userdata\panshriv\Desktop\putty.exe" "pankaj@10.91.124.171" -pw "mypassword"

- My putty.exe is in my desktop
- My username is "pankaj"
- My password is "mypassword"

Comment: That's not an `ssh` connection.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to input an IP address from the user. Fill in username and password with double quote "":

```
@echo off
set /p id="Enter IP Address: "

START "C:\Program Files\putty.exe" -ssh %id% -l username -pw "password" 

@echo
```

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to do this::

1. put your password in "" and run in command prompt as

**start C:\software\putty.exe -ssh server_name -l user -pw "MyPassword$1"**

OR

2. Create a file Connection123.bat with below command

**start C:\software\putty.exe -ssh server_name -l user -pw %1**

save the file 
and run the batch file as

**start c:\Connection123.bat MyPassword$1**