# How to remote Shutdown Linux machine from Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2012, centos-7, remote-shutdown

Is there a way I can shutdown a Linux box (CentOS) from a batch file on a Windows machine (win 2012 Server)?

Comment: -1 first look how do you shutdown a linux machine locally(SHUTDOWN COMMAND) then look at how to issue commands remotely(SSH).  so ssh to it and issue a shutdown command as root.

Comment: Yep, I realize that I can use an SSH client like puTTY and issue a shutdown command from there but was looking for something that can be called from a batch file directly to automate the shutdown process in one click.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/736665/ssh-to-a-remote-server-using-putty-through-windows-batch Please check out the answers here and then edit your question with any addition information you may need to complete the solution. Yours is a question is pointing at useful information, it just needs a little work on your part to become a really good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final solution I went with was using PLink.exe which is installed in the puTTY package, then create a batch file:

StopServer1.bat

```
"C:\Program files (x86)\puTTY\plink.exe" -ssh -root@Server1 -pw <password> shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more elaborate solutions, but a cheap and cheerful one is to use a flag file in a shared directory and a task which checks its existence, eg:-

```
if [ -r {shared-dir}/ShutDown ]; then rm {shared-dir}/ShutDown; shutdown -h now; fi
```

You can run this either in a loop with a `sleep 60` (say) command, or as a single command in a script run repeatedly from cron.

Your windows server simply creates `{shared-dir}/ShutDown` whenever it wants a  shut-down.

I hope it goes without saying that `{shared-dir}` must be writeable from the Linux system, to allow the deletion which both prevents a reboot loop and enables the Windows server to know when the shut-down request has been received and acted on.